# Login is not working in android with Openfire 4.1.5?

Tags: android, performance, openfire, smack

I have updated my Openfire server in 4.1.5 then login functionality is not working.In the previous version at the time of login I was using jid@domin name then it was working fine.But in the new version, it's not wotking. But if I remove @domain from jid its works in the new version. 
I am not getting how can i manage the old user.

Comment: U need to update Android app also because they have changed in library

Comment: maybe use openfire plugins to login